# Umbraco Workflow for content publishing

Tags: umbraco, umbraco7

I'm building a CMS solution using Umbraco 7 version. I have a requirement to add a workflow before content getting published to the site. Something similar to Content Creator creates a blog post -> send for Editor approval and once the editor approves it contents getting published to the public site.

`Draft-> Send for Approval(to an Editor)-> Approve -> publish`.

I know Umbraco has workflow feature for the Forms. Is there any way to integrate a workflow to the back office content publishing? Any thoughts or workarounds to achieve this??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, there is a simple approval workflow built in:
 http://nurhak-kaya.blogspot.com/2018/08/umbraco-notifications-save-and-send-for.html

It looks like it should cover your needs, though. If not, you could take a look at Plumber: https://our.umbraco.com/packages/backoffice-extensions/plumber-workflow-for-umbraco/

Comment: Awesome. I tried the first approach. Works like a charm

Comment: I'm a big fan of Plumber and it's open source too so you can customize it (if you want to do anything more complicated). I wrote a blog post on this process, in case it's useful to someone in the future: https://durabledigital.com/stories/articles/umbraco-workflow-management-and-plumber/

Comment: @WheretheresaWill Plumber is free compatible with Umbraco 7.x. Plumber 2 is paid compatible with Umbraco 8.x https://github.com/nathanwoulfe/Plumber-2